# Get different values for each day from total of 35 days PHP

Tags: php, math, formula, divide

I am trying to achieve a kind of result in which I can get the different values for 'each day' against a 'total value' for the '35 days' and then I want to save the value in the column (ROI) of user table:

Currently I am trying to achieve like this:

```
$total_days = 35;
$total_amount = 200;
$arr = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $total_days; ++$i)
{
    $arr[] = rand(0.0, 1000.0);
}

$actual_sum = array_sum($arr);

for($i = 0; $i < $total_days; ++$i)
{
    $arr[$i] *= $total_amount /$actual_sum;
    //echo $arr[$i]."<BR><BR>";
}

$sum = array_sum($arr);

//echo "Sum = ".$sum;
```

And the result is:

```
*********************************************

5.2625698324022

4.9162011173184

0.27932960893855

5.9776536312849

9.7430167597765

and so on for the total 35 days

Sum = 200

**********************************************
```

This is resulting me all days values together, Now what I need to do is to get only one day's value and then I will insert that value in the table and this code will run through the cron job daily for 35 days.

My question is how to get only one value in the variable so I can save that in the table?

Like this:

```
$value_to_insert = 5.26 (the first generated value for first day of cron job running);

And there will be the same for 2nd day cron job ($value_to_insert should be = 4.91)
```

Also if is there any good Idea that How can I manage all days values so If the cron will run on 35th day, the all inserted value should be equal to $total_amount (200) ?

My table structure is:

```
********************************
UserID (int)
UserName (varchar)
Email (varchar)
Earning (int)
LastROIEarning (int)
Date (timestamp)
********************************
```

Comment: Is it possible for this cronjob start whenever or is it always on the 1th of a month  or similar?

Comment: The cron job will be executing daily, means each day for 35 days. And whenever the cron job executes. The code will be executed.

Comment: So it could start whenever but only for 35 days ahead?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer on your question:
*My question is how to get only one value in the variable so I can save that in the table?*
would be: Just reference the $arr with a key, like `$arr[0]` is the first value, `$arr[1]` is the second value etc...

But I believe that's not your actual question. It's more about how to achieve that in combination with a cron-job.

Here's a solution I've came up with:

**This is a current example output from your code:**

```
array (size=35)
  0 => float 4.1004135360242
  1 => float 5.0905702137574
  2 => float 4.1819558506611
  3 => float 1.8754732366474
  4 => float 1.3512726425534
  5 => float 9.7035354417846
  6 => float 3.7509464732949
  7 => float 7.7581687925913
  8 => float 4.6013163259363
  9 => float 2.5394606558332
  10 => float 2.5627584600151
  11 => float 1.6774419011008
  12 => float 10.553905294426
  13 => float 10.938319063428
  14 => float 6.0923757935815
  15 => float 8.0610402469567
  16 => float 10.099598112878
  17 => float 9.7501310501485
  18 => float 2.3064826140136
  19 => float 10.495660783971
  20 => float 11.637253188887
  21 => float 2.9821189352903
  22 => float 8.3406138971402
  23 => float 10.099598112878
  24 => float 6.0457801852175
  25 => float 0.46595608363912
  26 => float 0.51255169200303
  27 => float 2.108451278467
  28 => float 1.7123886073738
  29 => float 6.2205137165822
  30 => float 7.5950841633176
  31 => float 10.949967965519
  32 => float 1.1765391111888
  33 => float 6.7563632127672
  34 => float 5.9059933601258
```

I would save **all** these values into an empty table (`cronvalues`) with a structure like this:

```
id   value                used
1    4.1004135360242      0
2    5.0905702137574      0
3    4.1819558506611      0
4    1.8754732366474      0 
etc (up to 35 rows)
```

This generation of the data should be your current php file and be called `generate.php` or similar.

The file that is called daily could be `cronday.php`:

**cronday.php:**

1. *SELECT RANDOMIZED ID* from the table cronvalues

   *SQL:* 
   `SELECT id FROM cronvalues WHERE used = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

   Store value in `$result_id`
2. *UPDATE VALUE* in database that it is used now

   *SQL*: `UPDATE cronvalues SET used = 1 WHERE id={$result_id}`

In these steps above you could keep track of the current sum by using SQL:

```
SELECT SUM() AS currentsum FROM cronvalues WHERE used = 1
```

Above is based on the fact the the cronjob is only execute ONCE a day. If you want to do an extra control you may add an extra column in the table to verify this with current date.

I'm not sure this was exactly what you meant but I hope it will give some ideas how you can solve your problem.